# Changing marker direction to a specific point

Tags: android, maps

I built an android app with a map and I added some custom markers, let me show you.

[image]

I want to rotate that picture to points to an another point. I saved the coordinations for the other point too.

This is what is saved by now in the database about this marker.

[image]

Latitude and Longitude are the actual marker's position, and del_lat, del_lng is the delivery address which I want to point to. How can I rotate the image in that position?

Here's my ClusterManagerRenderer

```
public class ClusterManagerRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<FinalMarkerCluster> {
    private final IconGenerator iconGenerator;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private final int markerWidth;
    private final int markerHeight;

    public ClusterManagerRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<FinalMarkerCluster> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);


        iconGenerator = new IconGenerator(context.getApplicationContext());
        imageView = new ImageView(context.getApplicationContext());
        markerWidth = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_marker_image);
        markerHeight = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_marker_image);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(markerWidth,markerHeight));
        int padding = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_marker_padding);

        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding,padding,padding);
        iconGenerator.setContentView(imageView);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(FinalMarkerCluster item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
       imageView.setImageResource(item.getIconPicture());
        Bitmap icon = iconGenerator.makeIcon();
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon)).title(item.getTitle());

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster<FinalMarkerCluster> cluster) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here I'm creating the Marker

```
 private void setRendering(List<MarkerCluster> markerClusters) {
        for(int i = 0 ;i < markerClusters.size() ;i++) {

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(markerClusters.get(i).getLatitude(), markerClusters.get(i).getLongitude());
            String title = markerClusters.get(i).getTitle();
            String snippet = markerClusters.get(i).getSnippet();
            LatLng delLatLng = new LatLng(markerClusters.get(i).getDel_lat(), markerClusters.get(i).getDel_lng());
            int pic = markerClusters.get(i).getIconPicture();
            String offerid = markerClusters.get(i).getOfferid();
            FinalMarkerCluster finalMarkerCluster = new FinalMarkerCluster(
                    latLng,
                    title,
                    snippet,
                    pic,
                    offerid,
                    delLatLng
            );
            finalMarkerClusters.add(finalMarkerCluster);
        }



        if(mGoogleMap != null) {
            if(mClusterManager == null) {
                mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<FinalMarkerCluster>(getApplicationContext(),mGoogleMap);
            }
            if(mClusterManagerRender == null) {
                mClusterManagerRender = new ClusterManagerRenderer(getApplicationContext(),mGoogleMap,mClusterManager);
                mClusterManager.setRenderer(mClusterManagerRender);
            }
            for(int j = 0; j< finalMarkerClusters.size();j++) {
                mClusterManager.addItem(finalMarkerClusters.get(j));
            }
            mClusterManager.cluster();

        }
    }
```

And here's the MarkerCluster object

```
public class FinalMarkerCluster implements ClusterItem {

    private LatLng position;
    private String title;
    private String snippet;
    private int iconPicture;
    private String offerId;
    private LatLng deliveryPosition;

    public FinalMarkerCluster(LatLng position, String title, String snippet, int iconPicture, String offerId, LatLng deliveryPosition) {
        this.position = position;
        this.title = title;
        this.snippet = snippet;
        this.iconPicture = iconPicture;
        this.offerId = offerId;
        this.deliveryPosition = deliveryPosition;
    }


WITH GETTERS AND SETTERS
```

I just want to rotate the image in that point, Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't address clustering but for simple marker rotation two things come in handy:

To determine bearing from point A (the lower-right marker on sample screen) to point B use `SphericalUtil.computeHeading`:

```
        // add two markers
    LatLng m1 = new LatLng(40.763807, -80.362280);
    LatLng m2 = new LatLng(40.821666, -80.636242);
    MarkerOptions m1o = new MarkerOptions().position(m1).title("m1").flat(true);
    MarkerOptions m2o = new MarkerOptions().position(m2).title("m2").flat(true);

    double hdg = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(m1,m2);
```

And to rotate the first marker (A, lower-right) in the direction of the second marker apply the bearing to marker to rotate:

```
    m1o.rotation((float)hdg);
```

And add markers

```
    mMap.addMarker(m1o);
    mMap.addMarker(m2o);
```

Note the use of `flat` which maintains north-alignment on screen rotation.  If that is not desired then remove the `flat` for the non-rotated- markers.

Note also the rotation is about the anchor point which may need further consideration.

In this image the screen has been rotated so "screen-up" is ~NNW for demo purposes.

[image]